# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting AND-Function

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

**UPDATE:**

I try to use conditional formatting for the following case:

If a cell in column C (starting with C9) `Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(9, 3), Tabelle3.Cells(lastcell, 3))`

1. is not empty `Cell <>""`
   AND
2. fullfills a criteria which is stated in Tabelle4 Cell B2 `Tabelle4.Range("B2")`

its `Interior.Color` should be changed to `Cellclr` and its `Font.Color` to `Fontclr`

**Start Old Post:**
I looked through various posts about conditional formatting but I couldn't find any, that is preciously solving my problem.

I want to apply conditional formatting to a Excel workbook which will be constantly extanded. Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
Sub ConForm()

Dim lastcell As Long
Dim Cellclr As Long
Dim Fontclr As Long

lastcell = Tabelle3.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Cellclr = RGB(232, 245, 246)
Fontclr = RGB(26, 155, 167)

Set C = Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(9, 3), Tabelle3.Cells(lastcell, 3))

    With C.FormatConditions.Add( _
            Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";"$C9.Value <= Tabelle4.Range(""B2"").Value)")
        .Interior.Color = Cellclr
        .Font.Color = Fontclr
    End With

End Sub
```

If I just use the following range and formula:

```
Range("C9")
Formula1:="=C9<>""""")
```

the code works out for Cell C9. However, as already mentioned, it should be this Formula

```
=AND($C9<>"""";"$C9.Value <= Tabelle4.Range(""B2"").Value
```

be applied for the range

```
Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(9, 3), Tabelle3.Cells(lastcell, 3))
```

Does someone know where I made a mistake/mistakes and how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you look at the color-coding on this code, the `End Sub` is in red text. So is the `End With`. Red text is strings or numbers. Since I'm not sure what the formula should look like once it's in the conditional formatting, I'm not sure where there is a missing/extra `"`; but you should definitely take a closer look at that string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the colours on your formatting to see what's a string and what's not - you have a mysterious extra `"` in the middle of your formula, which will prevent the code from compiling in the first place.  You have also tried to put VBA code (`Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value`) into an Excel formula, which won't work.

If you want to fix the value of `Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value` when the macro is run, you can change

```
Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";"$C9.Value <= Tabelle4.Range(""B2"").Value)")
```

to

```
Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";$C9<=" & Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value & ")")
```

Comment: Thanks for your support as well :) Your function seems to be the same as the one from PEH and with this function the code is executed. 1. However as stated above, the formatting condition is in all cells the same one. They are all reffering to cell C9. How can I make this flexible? 2. Even though, the conditional formatting forumla is inserted the interior and font color didn't change. Do you know what's going on here? :)

Comment: The formula is locked to Column C, but (if the top cell is Row 9) the row should change as the code moves down.  I *do* notice you don't have a line in your shown code to delete existing Conditional Formatting - have you had a look at the Conditional Formatting that has been placed in from "Home" > "Conditional Formatting" to makes sure there is not other formatting overrriding the new stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings and values correctly.

Example:

```
MyVariable = "ccc"
result = "aaa" & "bbb" & MyVariable & "AnotherString"
'result is "aaabbbcccAnotherString"
```

I'm not sure what you tried but probably you meant something like

```
Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";" & Range("$C9").Value <= Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value & ")")
```

Or more likely something like

```
Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";$C9<=Tabelle4!B2)")
```

Update:

```
Formula1:="=AND($C9<>"""";$C9<=" & Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value & ")")
```

Comment: I have just updated my post, to explain more briefly what I intend to do. :)

Comment: Thanks, with this function the code is executed. **1.** However, the formatting condition is in all cells the same one. They are all reffering to cell C9. How can I make this flexible? **2.** Even though, the conditional formatting forumla is inserted the interior and font color didn't change.  Do you know what's going on here? :)

Comment: @HPM This should work as expected. Make sure you delete all old conditions that might already exists for this range, before applying a new condition!